# Как сделать что бы бот давал другому боту определенный функционал aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram, бот

Всех приветствую.
Стало интересно как можно сделать что бы главный бот выдавал определенный функционал другому боту созданному через bot father
Как пример бот для отложенного постинга постов в канал
Когда в главного бота забивается токен бота сделанного через bot father и уже откладывание постов можно делать в не в главном боте
И все это на aiogram

Comment: Актуально
Актуально